# iis 500.19 error on unc path with colon char

Tags: iis, unc

i have a web site on local disc and another on unc disk
i saw lots of 500 error on logs
i wanted to search the problem
problem is look like this

when i try to reach on local site
http://localhost/http://foo-bar.com

i get a 404 not found error

but

when i try to reach it on unc site
i get a 500.19 configuration error like this

```
    Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x800700a1
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file
Config File    \\?\UNC\NAS1\SharedStorage\WebApplications\Default\www\http:\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/http:/foo-bar.com
Physical Path      \\NAS1\SharedStorage\WebApplications\Default\www\http:\foo-bar.com
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
```

unc site has a full permission with administrative right

iis not started to use any modules before i get this error, so i cant use failed request tracing rule

Comment: i found something similar to my problem but not a solution to me
https://support.microsoft.com/tr-tr/kb/932552

Comment: i trace w3wpg with process monitor and i found something
when w3wp ask folder www\http:\ and www\http:\web.config in local site get "NOT FOUND" but when i try it with unc site, w3wp ask folder www\http:\ get "NOT FOUND" and "www\http:\web.config" get "PATH SYNTAX BAD"